# OAuth2.0 "No Flow" server on Restlet

Tags: oauth, restlet

Man, what a nightmare!

Can anybody PLEASE point me in the direction of any kind of a proper tutorial or example of how to implement an OAuth2.0 server on Restlet (2.2 or 2.1.1).  The only thing resembling a tutorial that I managed to find is [this one here](http://web.archive.org/liveweb/http://web.archive.org/web/20120204015421/http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/28-restlet/392-restlet.html), but don't get too excited just yet, because it seems that the code in the framework is being changed more frequently than this tutorial is being updated.

Aside from the above mentioned article, there seems to be a near complete absence of any useful search results on this matter on Google.  Surely someone out there must have got this right and is using OAuth2.0 on Restlet?

I did in fact manage to get my OAuth2.0 server as far as to return an access token to me (after spending hours analyzing the source code of the *AccessTokenResource.java* file), but it seems that it is only validating the *client id* and not the *client secret*.  Assuming I can sort that out, I am still faced with the task of actually protecting the resources (which should be the job of the *OAuthAuthorizer*, but that appears to no longer even be present after 2.1.1).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension is a work in progress. Please note that OAuth 2.0 has only recently been finalized.

We are currently updating the 2.2 branch to a very recent draft (31). The code has been updated and the documentation indeed needs to follow.

2.2 is still under development and isn't ready for production. We are looking for testers and contributors (code and doc) at this point.

In 2.2 OAuthAuthorizer has been split.

See this issue for additional details:
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/pull/644

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification!  I will certainly keep an eye on that ongoing discussion.

Is there a workable, stable version that can be used in a production environment at this time (based on an older draft of course)?  If so, where would one find documentation or examples on that?

Comment: A major upgrade to OAuth 2.0 final is currently underway. I would recommend targeting this. We'll be working on better documentation for 2.2 M2/M3: https://github.com/FantomJAC/restlet-framework-java/commit/2a1f9ea8ec6d5d01258dbc0db25b247267a273b2

Comment: Hey @JeromeLouvel, I saw that Restlet now fully supports OAuth 2.0 RFC. I am using version 2.2.1, Are there any updates on documentation or examples? Thanks!

Comment: Not at this point unfortunately, we are looking for contributors on thi front